# How to propagate the exception to the calling thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

How to propagate the exception to the calling thread in java. Like I have a main thread and I am creating another thread and say new created thread throws an exception. I want to propagate that exception to main thread. How to achieve that.

Comment: mmm... catch the exception in the thread and re-throw?

Comment: @Shreyas What's the point of that?

Comment: no point...true. Also if not handled in the thread, it would anyways propagate to the main thread. But the question mentioned 'i want to propagate' explicitly. So I guessed the user may want to throw some user defined exception to the main thread.

Comment: Exceptions are synchronous. Things that happen in other threads are not synchronous. One approach would be to have thread A "return" something like a `Callable` object to thread B, and have the `get()` method raise the exception in thread B at the point where thread B asks for the value.

Comment: Thanks, I have used the same solution